# Set multiple Style properties from single Binding (de-multiplex a key into several Resources?)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**Scenario:** As an Embedded Software Engineer, I want my MVVM View to set multiple properties in my XAML style from a single binding to my ViewModel.

**Given:** My view contains a Style that is applied to a Button, and my ViewModel has a 'key' property.

*Relevant bits of the ButtonStyle.xaml ResourceDictionary:*

```
<!-- This is the style used for Buttons -->
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <!-- Other, common Style setters live here -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0"
                               Source="{Binding Path=Key, 
                                        Converter={r:ButtonImageConverter}}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Content="{Binding Path=Key,
                                         Converter={r:ButtonTextConverter}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <!-- ControlTemplate.Triggers and other stuff -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*Relevant bits of the CommandViewModel.cs class:*

```
// The relevant bits of the ViewModel class that the button is bound to
public class CommandViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged, ICommand
{
    private String Key;
    {
        get { return key; }
        set { OnPropertyChanged(ref key, value); }
    }

    // ... Plus implementation of OnPropertyChanged, ICommand, etc.
}
```

**When:** The Button is bound to the ViewModel object.

*The binding from the ViewModel to the Button:*

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" 
    DataContext="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
    Content="{Binding Path=Key}" 
    Command="{Binding Path=Command}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

**Then:** Several of the Style properties are set (using Value Converters) based on a collection of Resources associated with the 'key' property.

*Incomplete implementation of one of the Value Converters (the other is very similar and not included here):*

```
public class ButtonTextConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    // This is just so that I can reference it in the XAML as:
    // Converter={r:ButtonImageConverter}
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        String index = value as String;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(index))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The name to convert cannot be Null or Empty", "value");
        }

        // The code gets here just fine, with index containing the same
        // string as the CommandViewModel.Key property.
        // But ...
        // How can I find a the String Resouce, using the index, when
        // there may be several all related to the same Control?  I.e.
        // the ButtonImageConverter will also find a String containing
        // the URI path for the image to display on the Button.
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Architecturally, my View is an Assembly that contains all of my XAML (no code behind for any of the XAML components) and resources.  The ViewModel is in a different assembly and knows nothing about resources, images, localised text, cultures, etc.

One solution, which would break my architecture, would be to add more properties to the ViewModel class and let it pull the various values from an XML file.  I don't like this because then my Model and ViewModel are both polluted by View stuff.  I want to keep all that stuff in the View.

Another solution that I've looked at it using custom resource classes.  The [ResourceManager.GetObject Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963f81yd.aspx) page contains some example code for how to create a `.RESX` resource file that contains custom resources.  I've tried this, but the result is beyond my current comprehension, and it's not in my customer's best interest for me to try to lean how to use the Microsoft ResX schema.  However, this may be the way to go, if there's an easy way to save complex objects (that the Value Converters could use to de-multiplex the `Key`) as a single Resource entity.

What options do I have to allow different resources to be uniquely identified by the same identification 'key', depending on which Value Converter is trying to find the Resource?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've implemented is a little crude and relies on giving the resources different names, formed by appending the property name to the resource 'Key' name.  I've encapsulated that into a `ButtonResources` class that the `ValueConverter` classes use as a helper to get the actual resources.

```
internal class ButtonResources
{
    #region Static Fields

    private static ResourceManager resourceManager = 
        new ResourceManager("MyApplication.Resources.ButtonResources",
                            typeof(ButtonResources).Assembly);

    private static Dictionary<String,ButtonResources> resourceDictionary =
        new Dictionary<String, ButtonResources>();

    #endregion

    #region Instance Properties

    internal String Text { get; set; }
    internal BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    internal SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Instance Fields

    private String Name { get; set; }

    #endregion

    private ButtonResources(String buttonName)
    {
        this.Name = buttonName;
    }

    private void LoadResources(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Load the button Text 
        Text = resourceManager.GetString(Name + "Text", culture);

        // Load the image file from a URI.
        // See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx
        // (It's regrettably complex, but there are lots of examples on t'interweb.)
        String imageName = resourceManager.GetString(Name + "Image", culture);
        Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/"
            + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            + ";component/Resources/"
            + imageName, UriKind.Absolute));

        // Convert the colour resource to a suitable Brush object.
        String colourName = resourceManager.GetString(Name + "Colour", culture);
        Brush = new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(colourName) as SolidColorBrush;
    }

    internal static ButtonResources FindButton(String buttonName, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(buttonName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The name of the button cannot be Null or Empty",
                                        "buttonName");
        }

        ButtonResources buttonResources;

        // Check whether the requested resource has been loaded yet.
        if (resourceDictionary.ContainsKey(buttonName))
        {
            buttonResources = resourceDictionary[buttonName];
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a new instance with the requested name.
            buttonResources = new ButtonResources(buttonName);

            // Load the object's properties from the Resources.
            buttonResources.LoadResources(culture);

            // Add the new object to the dictionary.
            resourceDictionary.Add(buttonName, buttonResources);
        }

        return buttonResources;
    }
}
```

Each of the `ValueConverter` classes is simplified somewhat:

```
public abstract class ValueConverter
    : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                                      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}

public class ButtonTextConverter : ValueConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Use the ButtonResources helper to find the text to place on the button.
        return ButtonResources.FindButton(value as String, culture).Text;
    }
}

public class ButtonImageConverter : ValueConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Use the ButtonResources helper to find the image to put on the button.
        return ButtonResources.FindButton(value as String, culture).Image;
    }
}

public class ButtonColourConverter : ValueConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Use the ButtonResources helper to find the brush to use for the button.
        return ButtonResources.FindButton(value as String, culture).Brush;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** In the Solution Explorer, I have cleared the `Custom Tool` field of the `ButtonResources.resx` file.  This is because the `ButtonResources` class handles everything that the code created by the resgen.exe tool does.

I'm pretty sure that the `CultureInfo` stuff is going to go wrong if I ever need to localise the resources, but it works at the moment so I'll address that problem if it ever arises.

In addition to the localisation issue, the `ButtonResources` class could probably do with some extra code to handle cases where a named resource isn't present, whereby an acceptable default is provided, or at least something other than `null`.  Again, this isn't causing a problem at the moment, so I've done nothing to fix it here.